# Redis Pubsub performance for remote clients

Tags: python, http, testing, redis, notifications

I am building a notification model with Redis as database. With every addition to a particular key in the database, I notify the  remote client(written with Redis-py) using Redis's pubsub feature and also a HTTP based notification.

While running performance test and comparing the times between Redis PUBSUB notification and HTTP Response are fairly close( redis still being faster than HTTP by a few ms. Example. Redis notification takes 47 ms and HTTP notification takes 56 ms).

I was assuming Redis PUBSUB would be much faster than HTTP. Is this the expected performance of redis notification over HTTP ? Is there a faster way to push notifications from Redis db (faster than HTTP)?

Comment: Adding to my question,

Are there any notification models that I can build with python which will be faster than redis pubsub?

Answer (score 0):

What is your ping to client instance? If underlying network is slow, there is nothing much you can do. Only switch to UDP custom protocol. Because expected performance of Redis PUBSUB is about 4k op/s with regular hardware. Also what is the message size you are transferring? If it is high, you're also bound to your network speed.

Comment: My message is a small dictionary object with 4-5 keys and value. Nothing complex.  Ping averages around 4 ms between client and server running redis. So my question is , is redis pubsub's performance equivalent to http?

Comment: With 4 ms ping you shouldn't get 47ms delivery. Something is wrong. And with http too. Are you sure you measure only delivery, not de/serialization costs?

Comment: No. I add a <start> time.time() stamp before the HTTP POST to the database, and measure <redisNotification > time.time() as soon as I get a notification from redis database and <httpresponse> time.time() as soon as I get response via http.

Comment: Who sends redis notification? HTTP notification? Is all of it placed on single machine? Can you post your setup more clearly?

Comment: Also, what is the output of `redis-cli --latency -h host -p port` ?

Comment: and `redis-cli --intrinsic-latency 100` (this one should be run on the server)?

Comment: redis-cli -a arista --latency -h host -p port
min: 0, max: 1, avg: 0.02 (3601 samples)

# redis-cli --intrinsic-latency 100
Max latency so far: 1 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 6 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 7 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 73 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 109 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 274 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 480 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 1280 microseconds.
Max latency so far: 2715 microseconds.
^C
489827298 total runs (avg latency: 0.2042 microseconds / 204.15 nanoseconds per run).

This is running on a VM

Comment: This is very strange that with 1 ms latency you see  47ms delay for notification. I suspect it is a client or server app code that creates a  delay. Also does client and server click synchronized?

Comment: sry, click = clock